# Convert LaTeX equations to Word 2007/2010 equations

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, latex, equations, equation-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to put LaTeX formulas in Word 2010?](https://superuser.com/questions/346162/how-to-put-latex-formulas-in-word-2010)

I'd like to rephrase the [LaTeX Equations in MS Word/OpenOffice?](https://superuser.com/questions/73238/latex-equations-in-ms-word-openoffice) question: Is there, by now, any software that can parse LaTeX code and convert it into a native Office 2007/2010 equation? I'd like to get rid of MathType for this purpose, see [Convert MathType equations to native Word 2007/2010 equations](https://superuser.com/questions/403933/convert-mathtype-equations-to-native-word-2007-2010-equations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GrindEq's [LaTex-to-Word](http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=latex2word) can do that, too. Shareware.

What I am missing is a functionality that would treat all text surrunded by $$ or \[ \] as LaTeX code and convert automatically.